# Mobile first Authorization failed for user admin

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKvh7.png)I am using mobile first platform in eclipse and trying to start mobile first console it gives the following error

> CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking
>   WorklightServices on /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/. The user is not
>   granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin,
>   worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer]. [AUDIT   ]
>   CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking
>   WorklightServices on /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/. The user is not
>   granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin,
>   worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer]. [AUDIT   ]
>   CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking
>   WorklightServices on /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/. The user is not
>   granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin,
>   worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer]. [AUDIT   ]
>   CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking
>   WorklightServices on /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/. The user is not
>   granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin,
>   worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer]. [AUDIT   ]
>   CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking
>   WorklightServices on /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/. The user is not
>   granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin,
>   worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer]. [AUDIT   ]
>   CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking
>   WorklightServices on /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/. The user is not
>   granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin,
>   worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer]. [AUDIT   ]
>   CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking
>   WorklightServices on /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/. The user is not
>   granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin,
>   worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer]. [AUDIT   ]
>   CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking
>   WorklightServices on
>   /management-apis/1.0/runtimes/notification/applications. The user is
>   not granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin,
>   worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer]. [AUDIT   ]
>   CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user admin while invoking
>   WorklightConsole on /index.html. The user is not granted access to any
>   of the required roles: [worklightadmin, worklightmonitor,
>   worklightoperator, worklightdeployer].

Comment: Did you change anything in your server.xml before this happened? Does this also happen a completely new project

Answer (score 1):

To open the console you must first start the server.

From the Servers view in Eclipse, click the 'play' button to start the server. You will then be able to open the console.

Also, from the errors it does sound like you altered the server's configuration in the server.xml file? Double check this by creating a new project in MobileFirst Studio and then just starting the server without any alterations. The console should open successfully.

Comment: That does not make sense. Your installation is ruined. Reinstall.

Comment: yes i have done that . now it show a new error one min let me upload....i have uploaded the image link on the begiing of the question please verify